# change report is being generated progress indicator

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I would like to change the report is being generated progress indicator icon
(circle) with a custom one.

We're on: SQL Server 2008 R2.  Reporting Services 2008 R2.

I know that I can customize the text with IReportViewerMessages Interface.
Is there a similar approach for changing the progress indicator icon?

Best regards,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Add new class inhertis from `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.IReportViewerMessages` and change the text you want
chek the following link for more
[IReportViewerMessages Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN will get you on the right path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages.aspx). In addition, here's a Dutch implementation of mine complete with the original text in English:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

namespace SomeApplication
{
    public class DutchReportViewerMessages : IReportViewerMessages, IReportViewerMessages2, IReportViewerMessages3
    {
        #region IReportViewerMessages Members

        // English value: Back to Parent Report
        public string BackButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Terug naar het vorige rapport"; }
        }

        // English value: Change Credentials
        public string ChangeCredentialsText
        {
            get { return "Wijzig Rechten"; }
        }

        // English value: Change Credentials
        public string ChangeCredentialsToolTip
        {
            get { return "Wijzig Rechten"; }
        }

        // English value: Current Page
        public string CurrentPageTextBoxToolTip
        {
            get { return "Huidige Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: Document Map
        public string DocumentMap
        {
            get { return "Document Map"; }
        }

        // English value: Show / Hide Document Map
        public string DocumentMapButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Toon / Verberg Document Map"; }
        }

        // English value: Export
        public string ExportButtonText
        {
            get { return "Exporteer"; }
        }

        // English value: Export
        public string ExportButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Exporteer"; }
        }

        // English value: Export Formats
        public string ExportFormatsToolTip
        {
            get { return "Exporteer Formaten"; }
        }

        // English value: False
        public string FalseValueText
        {
            get { return "Onwaar"; }
        }

        // English value: Find
        public string FindButtonText
        {
            get { return "Zoek"; }
        }

        // English value: Find
        public string FindButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Zoek"; }
        }

        // English value: Next
        public string FindNextButtonText
        {
            get { return "Volgende"; }
        }

        // English value: Find Next
        public string FindNextButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Volgend Resultaat"; }
        }

        // English value: First Page
        public string FirstPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Eerste Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: Enter a valid page number
        public string InvalidPageNumber
        {
            get { return "Voer een geldig paginanummer in"; }
        }

        // English value: Last Page
        public string LastPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Laatste Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: Next Page
        public string NextPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Volgende Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: The entire report has been searched.
        public string NoMoreMatches
        {
            get { return "Het volledige rapport is doorzocht."; }
        }

        // English value: NULL
        public string NullCheckBoxText
        {
            get { return "Geen waarde"; }
        }

        // English value: Null
        public string NullValueText
        {
            get { return "Geen waarde"; }
        }

        // English value: of
        public string PageOf
        {
            get { return "van"; }
        }

        // English value: Show / Hide Parameters
        public string ParameterAreaButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Toon / Verberg Parameters"; }
        }

        // English value: Password:
        public string PasswordPrompt
        {
            get { return "Wachtwoord:"; }
        }

        // English value: Previous Page
        public string PreviousPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Vorige Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: Print
        public string PrintButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Afdrukken"; }
        }

        // English value: Loading...
        public string ProgressText
        {
            get { return "Verwerken..."; }
        }

        // English value: Refresh
        public string RefreshButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Vernieuwen"; }
        }

        // English value: Find Text in Report
        public string SearchTextBoxToolTip
        {
            get { return "Zoek naar tekst binnen het rapport"; }
        }

        // English value: <Select a Value>
        public string SelectAValue
        {
            get { return "<Selecteer een waarde>"; }
        }

        // English value: (Select All)
        public string SelectAll
        {
            get { return "(Selecteer alles)"; }
        }

        // English value: Select a format
        public string SelectFormat
        {
            get { return "Selecteer een formaat"; }
        }

        // English value: The search text was not found.
        public string TextNotFound
        {
            get { return "De zoektekst is niet gevonden."; }
        }

        // English value: Today is {0}
        public string TodayIs
        {
            get { return "Vandaag is {0}"; }
        }

        // English value: True
        public string TrueValueText
        {
            get { return "Waar"; }
        }

        // English value: Log In Name:
        public string UserNamePrompt
        {
            get { return "Gebruikersnaam:"; }
        }

        // English value: View Report
        public string ViewReportButtonText
        {
            get { return "Toon Rapport"; }
        }

        // English value: Zoom
        public string ZoomControlToolTip
        {
            get { return "Zoom"; }
        }

        // English value: Page Width
        public string ZoomToPageWidth
        {
            get { return "Paginabreedte"; }
        }

        // English value: Whole Page
        public string ZoomToWholePage
        {
            get { return "Volledige pagina"; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IReportViewerMessages2 Members

        // English value: Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts.
        public string ClientNoScript
        {
            get { return "Uw browser ondersteunt geen JavaScript of deze ondersteuning is uitgeschakeld."; }
        }

        // English value: Unable to load client print control.
        public string ClientPrintControlLoadFailed
        {
            get { return "Het laden van het client print control is niet gelukt."; }
        }

        // English value: One or more data sources is missing a user name.
        public string CredentialMissingUserNameError(string dataSourcePrompt)
        {
            return "Een of meerdere databronnen missen een gebruikersnaam.";
        }

        // English value is different for each Rendering Extension. See comment behind each type.
        public string GetLocalizedNameForRenderingExtension(string format)
        {
            switch (format)
            {
                case "XML"   : return "XML databestand (.xml)";  // XML file with report data
                case "CSV"   : return "CSV databestand (.csv)";  // CSV (comma delimited)
                case "PDF"   : return "PDF document (.pdf)";     // PDF
                case "MHTML" : return "Webarchief (.mhtml)";     // MHTML (web archive)
                case "EXCEL" : return "Excel rekenblad (.xls)";  // Excel
                case "IMAGE" : return "Afbeelding (.tif)";       // TIFF file
                case "WORD"  : return "Word document (.doc)";    // Word
                default      : return null;
            }
        }

        // English value: Select a value
        public string ParameterDropDownToolTip
        {
            get { return "Selecteer een waarde"; }
        }

        // English value: Please select a value for the parameter '{0}'.
        public string ParameterMissingSelectionError(string parameterPrompt)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Selecteer een waarde voor de parameter '{0}'", parameterPrompt);
        }

        // English value: Please enter a value for the parameter '{0}'. The parameter cannot be blank.
        public string ParameterMissingValueError(string parameterPrompt)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Selecteer een waarde voor de parameter '{0}'. De parameter mag niet leeg zijn.", parameterPrompt);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IReportViewerMessages3 Members

        // English value: Loading...
        public string CalendarLoading
        {
            get { return "Verwerken..."; }
        }

        // English value: Cancel
        public string CancelLinkText
        {
            get { return "Annuleer"; }
        }

        // English value: pageCount if PageCountMode.Actual, else pageCount suffixed with a ?
        public string TotalPages(int pageCount, PageCountMode pageCountMode)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}{1}", pageCount, pageCountMode == PageCountMode.Estimate ? "~" : String.Empty);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

More info here: http://blogs.infosupport.com/localizing-microsoft-reportviewer/